# Rust: Using two u8 struct fields as a u16

Tags: struct, rust, unions

For a Gameboy emulator, you have two u8 fields for registers A and F, but they can sometimes be accessed as AF, a combined u16 register.

In C, it looks like you can do something like this:

```c
struct {
    union {
        struct {
            unsigned char f;
            unsigned char a;
        };
        unsigned short af;
    };
};
```

(Taken from [here](https://cturt.github.io/cinoop.html))

Is there a way in Rust, ideally without `unsafe`, of being able to access two u8s as `registers.a`/`registers.f`, but also be able to use them as the u16 `registers.af`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give you a couple of ways to do it. First is a straightforward unsafe analogue but without boilerplate, the second one is safe but explicit.

1. Unions in rust are very similar, so you can translate it to this:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Inner {
    f: u8,
    a: u8,
}

#[repr(C)]
union S {
    inner: Inner,
    af: u16,
}

// Usage:

// Putting data is safe:
let s = S { af: 12345 };
// but retrieving is not:
let a = unsafe { s.inner.a };
```

2. Or as an alternative you may manually do all of the explicit casts wrapped in a structure:

```
#[repr(transparent)]
// This is optional actually but allows a chaining,
// you may remove these derives and change method
// signatures to `&self` and `&mut self`.
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct T(u16);

impl T {
    pub fn from_af(af: u16) -> Self {
        Self(af)
    }
    
    pub fn from_a_f(a: u8, f: u8) -> Self {
        Self::from_af(u16::from_le_bytes([a, f]))
    }

    pub fn af(self) -> u16 {
        self.0
    }

    pub fn f(self) -> u8 {
        self.0.to_le_bytes()[0]
    }

    pub fn set_f(self, f: u8) -> Self {
        Self::from_a_f(self.a(), f)
    }

    pub fn a(self) -> u8 {
        self.0.to_le_bytes()[1]
    }

    pub fn set_a(self, a: u8) -> Self {
        Self::from_a_f(a, self.f())
    }
}

// Usage:

let t = T::from_af(12345);
let a = t.a();

let new_af = t.set_a(12).set_f(t.f() + 1).af();
```

Comment: Thank you. I might end up going with the first example for ease of use, even if `unsafe` code is frowned upon.

Comment: @DeeBo the second example is a bit more portable because it's explicit about using little-endian packing; but in practice there aren't many big-endian machines in use these days.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going for a bit of an in between, since I didn’t want to put unsafe everywhere. I have struct fields .a and .f as normal u8s without getters, then just a get_af() function, without the ‘Self’ chaining. I think to me it makes the most sense.

Comment: My implementation after this question can be found here: https://github.com/adamsoutar/gbrs/blob/master/src/gameboy/registers.rs#L59